# QtQuick: "StackView: You cannot push/pop recursively"

Tags: qml, qt-quick, qt5.3, qtquickcontrols

Getting this error message when running my QML application on Android. It's working fine in `qmlscene`, though.

Code looks like this:

*main.qml*:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    property Component loaderPage: LoaderPage {
        onGotoPage: changePage(page)
    }

    property Component loginPage: LoginPage {
        onGotoPage: changePage(page)
    }

    function changePage(page) {
        switch (page) {
            case "login":
                stackView.push({item: loginPage});
                break;
            default:
                print("panic!")
        }
    }

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        initialItem: loaderPage
    }
}
```

*Page.qml*:

```
Item {
    signal gotoPage (string page)
}
```

*LoaderPage.qml*:

```
Page {
    id: loaderPage

    // Triggered by some event:
    function() {
        loaderPage.gotoPage("login");
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why it's complaining about a recursive call?

I'm working with `QtQuick 2.3` and `QtQuick.Controls 1.2`.

Comment: Please, provide ready-to-use minimal project, so everyone can test it on his side. Also, can you explain what is your function `function()` inside Page related to (is there any error with function naming)?

Answer (score 0):

this error still persists in `QtQuick.Controls 2.2` lower, moving to 2.5 and higher should resolve it.